# Capture Browser close event without refresh event

Tags: javascript

I have question related to Browser close event..

How  to capture the Browser close event without refresh event.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    // do something
    return null;
};

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Comment: I have tried using window.onbeforeunload function which will work for both close and refresh events at time.so it didn,t work.

Comment: There is no built in way.  But an idea, not tried myself.  But on your onunload event, store the current datetime inside localstorage, and then on page load if the difference in time is say less than a second, you could assume it's a refresh.

Comment: Thanks keith for your replay..

Answer (score 0):

Using [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) but this will also be triggered when you reload the browser or moving to a different page by clicking on a link.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

Note: `window.onbeforeunload` will not work on touch devices except Android.

Comment: Thanks for the replay..But window.onbeforeunload  apply for both the close and refresh events at a time.so it wont work for the close event without refresh.

Comment: Like I said above, yes.. also there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};

$(function () {
    $("a").not('#LogOut').click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
});
```